# How to see how long users keep my app on their phones on average?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I have about 7 apps on Google Play Store and I was wondering is there any way, resource, or a website such as Google Play Console that shows how long users keep the app on their phone before deleting it? I can see how many users install it every day and how many users remove it but it doesn't really tell me if they really use it or not. So I'm looking for a graph that shows how long before they delete the app. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase analytics which will perfectly show you how many users opened your app today and how much of them gone through full app means check all activities of your app. Sor example your app have four screens:

1. Splash Screen
2. Main Activity
3. Second Activity
4. Third Activity

In Splash Screen user spend 1 minute and in Main Activity user spends 4 minutes but in  Second Activity use spends 1.5 minutes this all data is shown.

Firebase Analytics shows, user how much time spend in your activity and from where users are coming you can check your daily users.

Another you can try some alternatives or even better than this

- Data.ai
  link :- https://www.data.ai/en/
- AppstoreSpy (chrome extension)
  link :- https://appstorespy.com/
- AppMetrica
  link :- https://appmetrica.yandex.com/about
- Spidyhive (chrome extension)
  link :- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spidyhive-aso-g-play-help/dhdlnldaaeochhponebahbecamjdnkai/related
- Flurry
  link :- https://www.flurry.com/f/retention/
- Appsee
  link :- https://www.appsee.com/?cpnid=701b0000000Wd7c&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=tools_tracking_user_behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you use React Native you could try [Expo Analytics](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-analytics/) or something similar, but if you wish you could set up your own analytics server with only input of 'time_opened'/'time_closed' and storing summary for each id.
Anyway, you should ask users if they agree to send this data, and describe how you use it :)